# If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n} <\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}$ there's $N\in \mathbb{R}$ so for every $N <n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{n} <b_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_{n}, b_{n}$ be convergent sequences.

Prove that if $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n} <\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}$, then there exists $N\in \mathbb{R}$ so for every $N <n\in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow a_{n} <b_{n}$ .

By definition:

1. If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=L_{1}$ then $\forall 0 <\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}\exists N\in \mathbb{R}\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ( n >N\rightarrow \left| a_{n}-L_{1}\right|  < \varepsilon ) $
2. If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}=L_{2}$ then $\forall 0 <\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}\exists N\in \mathbb{R}\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ( n >N\rightarrow \left| b_{n}-L_{2}\right|  < \varepsilon ) $

So let $0 <\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then if we choose $N=\max \left\{ N_{1},N_{2}\right\}$ then for every $N <n\in \mathbb{N}$ we'll get:

1. $\left| a_{n}-L_{1}\right|  < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow L_{1}-\varepsilon  <a_{n} <L_{1}+\varepsilon $
2. $\left| b_{n}-L_{2}\right|  < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow L_{2}-\varepsilon  <b_{n} <L_{2}+\varepsilon $

But I got stuck here.
Would appreciate some help!

Comment: Do you know how to conclude when $b_n=0$?

Comment: You need to choose the correct $\varepsilon$.  I suggest $\varepsilon=\frac{b-a}{3}$, where $\lim a_n=a$ and $\lim b_n=b$.  That choice, along with the triangle inequality, will get you where you need to be.

Comment: @RobertShore Got it! Thanks! I chose it to be (b-a)/2. Works well also :)